# Call Javascript Function in Child iFrame with Cross Domain site but Same location JS file

Tags: javascript, html, browser, iframe, cross-domain

I am trying to do the following:

Main document calls a function in iFrame whose **URL is from a different location** but the Javascript function I'm trying to call loaded from the **same domain as the main document**.

Is there any way to do this?

To clarify:

- Main document: **http://www.main.com**
- iFrame document: **http://www.example.com**
- JS function i'm calling in iFrame is at **http://www.main.com/js/script.js**

I'm getting

```
Permission denied to access property 'js_function'
```

When doing

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.js_function(n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're doing. There was a "hack" that made use of two iframes (if I remember correctly).
Both that hack and the one you mention here are awfully obscure, and I wouldn't be surprised if they have been locked down knowingly.

The best fix I can think of is to load the code for `js_function()` in the main window (outside of the iframe).

Can you be more specific on what the JS code does? I may be able to help better.

Comment: It doesn't help that the Javascript file I'm trying to access is from the same domain as the main document?

Comment: No it doesn't. There are many reasons why not. If you recall how XSS works, they try limiting injection as much as possible. Disabling the protection just because the content came from elsewhere is a grave risk.

Comment: How could this be accepted as the answer? And XSS has nothing to do with script origin. For a real solution see my answer.

Comment: @Sean - You expected the OP to travel into the future (from 26th April) to find the answer you wrote up 11 minutes ago (2nd May)?

Comment: @Christian - No, I just thought it shouldn't have been marked as an answer in the first place :)

Comment: It clearly answered the behaviour the OP observed (which by the way, had everything to do with XSS). I clearly asked what he was doing but didn't get any further info.

Answer (score 5):

Even though the script is hosted on `main.com` it is *executed* in the context of `example.com` and therefore is considered to be part of `example.com` ... and therefore has no access to variables or functions in the `main.com` window.  You can hack around this with [various](http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/10/11/leveraging-window.name-transport-for-secure-and-efficient-cross-domain-communications.aspx) [cross](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) [domain](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000304.html) [communication](http://nicklothian.com/blog/2009/08/05/cross-domain-cross-window-javascript-communication/) hacks (or you can ignore IE < 8 and use [`window.postMessage`](http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/) by itself).

SEE ALSO: http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=109

Answer (score 0):

Use [easyXDM's](http://easyxdm.net) RPC feature, it combines XDM with RPC.
An example of this can be seen here: http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/methods.html